# Grabbing values from within a list of string arrays?

Tags: python, list, maya

How do you select/grab the values within a list of string arrays?

When I execute a code to read the contents in my files, it is as follows:

```
for line in testFile:
test = line.split()

#Output:
['1', '21', '32', '43', '54', '65', '76', '87']
['2', '31', '42', '53', '64', '75', '86', '97']
['3', '41', '52', '63', '74', '85', '96', '107']
...
...
```

However, now supposedly I would like to select and grab the first values - `1,2,3` in the output only, I got `['1', '21', '32', '43', '54', '65', '76', '87']` or the values of the last line, should I code it `print test[0]` or `for item in test..`

Meaning to say, if I decided to grab the values of column 3, it will gives me `32,42,52`, and if I grab column 6, it will gives me `65,75,85` etc
The number of columns are the same through and I asked this because I am either going to set the values in the rotation/translation attibutes while the first column being the frame number...

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to transpose the contents, with `zip` function, like this

```
with open("inputfile") as f:
    rows = zip(*[line.split() for line in f])

print rows[0]
```

We open the file with `open` and the `with` statement. Then, we read line by line and split every read line. So, we get a list of lists. Now, we apply each of those lists to `zip` function, which actually transposes them. After transposing, the rows become columns and the columns become rows. For example,

```
[[1, 2, 3]
 [4, 5, 6]
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

will become

```
[[1, 4, 7]
 [2, 5, 8]
 [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: just a quick question, as my output was `[(1, 2, 3),(4, 5, 6), ...]`, earlier when I tried printing it out, I got errors inciting - `# IndexError: list index out of range # ` Does this means I need to do some sort of conversion?

Comment: @dissidia If the number of rows and columns are different, then you may have to use proper index after transposing. Are you getting what I am saying?

Comment: Oh does this means the values for the number of rows must be the same as the number of columns?

Comment: @dissidia Not necessarily. Can you please give examples to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Really sorry, my bad in this case. It is actually working. I have forgotten to remove some of the coding I did and as a results, there is a conflict. Sorry!!

Comment: By the way, may I ask if it is possible to access the elements insides each list in this list array? So for example, I had wanted to access the '5' in row 2 - `[2, 5, 8]`, do i need to keep typing in `for item in rows[2]; item[1]` etc so as to access it?

Comment: @dissidia You can do, `rows[0][1]` to get the second item.

Comment: @thefoutheye cool, that is indeed what I want it. Thanks man! Hopefully I am able to implement this into my code :) Cheers!